# Перекрывается первая строка в редакторе кода

Tags: linux, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, manjaro

Sublime Text 3. Независимо от темы, верхняя часть первой строки всегда немного перекрывается верхним баром, это видно в сравнении со второй строкой.
Как это можно исправить?

OS: Manjaro

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

У меня всё вроде нормально. Попробуйте такие же шрифты поставить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]